# codeigniter restfull api POST method not calling from angular2. 404 error is coming

Tags: php, angular, codeigniter, angular2-services

I am using codeigniter restfull api and get method is calling but post method is not calling from angular2.

```
 this.api.post('quality/addeditquality',  this.formdata).subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
      });

  post(url: string, model: any): Observable<any> {
        let body = JSON.stringify(model);
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        return this._http.post(this.baseURL + url, body, options)
            .map((response: Response) => <any>response.json())
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

Comment: and the question is?and your errors are?

Comment: Please post value of `this.formdata`

Answer (score 0):

please update the code

```
  post(url: string, model: any): Observable<any> {
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
        let body = 'data=' + JSON.stringify(model);
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        return this._http.post(this.baseURL + url, body, options)
            .map((response: Response) => <any>response.json())
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

the php side use this code

```
$post = json_decode($_POST['data']);
```